# How do I change the location of the "Temp" folder to be a relative path?

Tags: interface, workflow, path

Here are my current User Preferences under the File tab:

[image: User preferences screenshot]

I'd like to make the "Temp" folder a relative path, sitting somewhere under the application's directory. So in this case, rather than it being *"D:\Applications\Blender 2.79\Temp\"*, it would be something like *"\Temp\"*.

Surely this should be very simple, but I've tried many combinations like //Temp, //\Temp\, \Temp\, etc, and every time it just resets to the default location.

Is it not possible to use relative paths for the Temp folder (I'm using Windows 10 if it makes any difference)? Thanks for any support you can give!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that field seems to accept only EXISTING folders, while "//" stands for "current folder", but it is referred to the "current SAVED file".

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/data_system/files/relative_paths.html says "You cannot enter relative paths into a new untitled blend-file. Save it before linking to external files."

the "temp" path in user preferences probably is needed absolute (and existing) because blender needs it even for itself to, eg, save the quit.blend file, useful to recover the last session (even if not saved), and that file is saved in the "temp" folder. So, blender MUST know well where exactly it is...

I mean this recover function could not work, probably, without being sure of the "temp" folder

[image]

Comment: Ah that explains it perfectly, thank you! So you couldn't specify a path relative to the application's executable file, even though that would always be there as long as you have Blender set up, because relative paths can only be linked to a .blend file and not the program itself?